# No instance for (Monoid a) arising from a use of ‘mempty’

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
data Logger a = Logger { getLog :: (a, [String]) }

instance Functor Logger where
    fmap f (Logger (x, log)) = Logger (f x, log)

instance Applicative Logger where
    pure x = Logger (x, [])
    (Logger (f, log1)) <*> (Logger (x, log2)) = Logger (f x, log1 `mappend` log2)

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Logger a) where
    (Logger (x, log1)) <> (Logger (y, log2)) =  Logger (x <> y, log1 <> log2)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Logger a) where
    mempty = Logger (mempty, [])

instance Monad Logger where
    return x = Logger (x, [])
    (Logger (x, log)) >>= f = Logger (res, log `mappend` newLog)
                                where (Logger (res, newLog)) = f x

instance Fail.MonadFail Logger where
    fail msg = mempty
```

I get the following error:

```
• No instance for (Monoid a) arising from a use of ‘mempty’
  Possible fix:
    add (Monoid a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        Fail.fail :: forall a. String -> Logger a
• In the expression: mempty
  In an equation for ‘Fail.fail’: Fail.fail msg = mempty
  In the instance declaration for ‘Fail.MonadFail Logger’
```

Why is there no instance for `Monoid a` when it clearly says `Monoid a => Monoid (Logger a)`? If my `Logger a` type in instantiated as `Monoid` why can't I use mempty in `fail` definition? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexis King explains very well what the problem is. What are some potential solutions? One option is to include failure explicitly:

```
data Logger a = Logger
  { theResult :: Either String a
  , theLog :: [String] }
```

Now you could write `fail m = Logger {theResult = Left m, theLog = []}`.

Another option, which I think is more common, is to make your logger a *monad transformer*:

```
newtype Logger m a = Logger
  { runLogger :: m (a, [String]) }

instance MonadTrans Logger where
  lift m = Logger $ do
    a <- m
    pure (a, [])
```

Now you can lift failure from the monad below:

```
instance MonadFail m => MonadFail (Logger m) where
  fail = lift . fail
```

Rather than writing everything yourself, you can use `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict`, or (in many/most cases better) [`Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.CPS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-CPS.html).

Comment: Thank you. Solution with the transformer worked.

Answer (score 6):

The error is not complaining about your `Monoid` instance. That part is fine.

What it *is* complaining about is your *use* of that instance in the definition of your `MonadFail` instance. When you write

```
fail msg = mempty
```

then GHC selects the `Monoid (Logger a)` instance. But that instance has a constraint on it, namely `Monoid a`. That means `a` must be known to have a `Monoid` instance at the place where `mempty` *is used*, which in this case is inside your `MonadFail` instance.

The root problem here is that `fail` has a very general type signature:

```
fail :: forall m a. MonadFail m => String -> m a
```

Note that the `a` here is universally quantified, which means the caller is allowed to instantiate it to *any type they want*. This means they could pick a type like `Void`, which does not have a `Monoid` instance. Therefore, your `Logger` simply type cannot support a `MonadFail` instance, since it would need to produce a value of a completely arbitrary type `a`, and there is no way for it to do so.